# Action on Google block adult keywords

Tags: actions-on-google

I am using cloud function for fulfillment on my action app on google assistant.

I want to recognise keywords related to alochol, tobaco, adult content etc and then tell user that we do not support such content on our action.

How can I implement this using either dialogflow or keyword blocking at cloud function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way in Dialogflow is to create an [entity](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/developer-entities). You can establish keywords and synonyms, which you can use for blocked words.

[image: https://dialogflow.com/docs/images/entities/dev-mapping.png?dcb_=0.5311554316300264]

Then, you can have an intent that will identify phrases with blocked words and allow you to handle that response separately.

[image: https://dialogflow.com/docs/images/entities/dev-comp003.png?dcb_=0.3682780228985896]

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am inclined to use it. It would require some training for dialogflow to get used to it.

Comment: It may take some time, but I think you'll end up with a more robust implementation, which will be valuable over time.